# What is best practice for dealing with asynchronous functions that call variables that may no longer be available?

Tags: javascript

My apologies if the title is confusing.

I have a situation where a user can open/close a dialog.

When the dialog is opened a series of asynchronous functions are called (in the case webworkers).

While these operations are completing the user can still close the dialog.

Upon which we clean up a load of variables and data relating to the dialog in question meaning that when the worker returns the variables it needs will no longer be available to it.

This is fine as we no longer need the result from the worker but of course, it throws a javascript error if the dialog is opened an closed quickly.

What is considered best practice for dealing with this?  Should I put the whole thing in a try/catch statement?

PLEASE NOTE:  This question is not specific to webworkers (I know I can use worker.terminate) so please structure any answers around asynchronous functions in general.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here is what I mean:

```
EXAMPLE.dialog = {
               init : function(){
                           this.cache = {
                                    //imagine lots of properties listed here
                           }
                           this.buildDialog();
               }
               buildDialog : function(){
                            //The dialog is built here

                           startFunctions();
               }
               startFunctions : function(){
                          //Perform several asynchronous functions here
                          //All of which reference this.cache.properties when they return
               },
               destroyDialog : function(){
                           //Dialog gets destroyed in DOM
                           delete this.cache;
               }       

}
```

**SOLUTION** : Ok stupidly while typing this example out a realized a very simple solution that does not require the use of `try/catch`.  By structuring all the required properties under one parent property (in this case `this.cache`) I can simply check for the existence of one property in the returning async functions.

Previously the properties were not structured in this manner meaning that checking for each individual one would be tedious and bloating.  My apologies for not realizing this sooner.

The code above to anyone reading, should be taken as a solution and NOT an example of the problem.

Comment: That's a bug, so fix it.

Comment: Could you show us a code sample of what you're working with?

Comment: @RickViscomi Positing the exact code would be meaningless and overkill so i'll knock up a tiny example of what we are dealing with.

Comment: That would be perfect, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of worrying about the individual object attributes you may or may not be setting - why not create an intermediary state which represents whether or not worker functions have a place to write results?  In your specific example this is controlled by whether or not a dialog box is open.

From your description I understand it to be something like:

- If the dialog box is open - returned workers will populate some object attributes
- If the dialog box is closed - returned workers will not populate some object attributes

So have the callback/return function of your workers begin by determining if they are allowed to populate data - which is determined by the dialog box state.  If it is open you are good to populate - if it is closed you can define some other behavior.

I think it would be better to aim for a general solution that doesn't couple the dialog box to the workers population flag, that way if the rules for the GUI change in the future you don't have worker functions looking directly at dialog box states.

Answer (score -1):

Eh, just check whether variables exist?

Comment: It's really not that simple in this case.  We will be referring to a huge number of object properties that may or may not exist.  Of course checking for the existence of the variable would work however this would require massively bloating the code.  If that's best practice then I guess it's the way we will go.  But that was the point of the question.

Comment: if(typeof foo ==='undefined') alert("That variable isn't in scope");

Comment: @gordyr That is a proper solution. I know it might be time consuming, but you will now in future to think about such things from the begining. You could wrap each asynchronous piece of code with `try{}catch{}` but since it is "massive", then you might catch things you don't want to catch (and JavaScript's exception handling is painful). And besides it is for lazy people. ;)

Comment: Indeed try/catch was kind of a last resort in my head.  However it would obviously be very easy and quick to implement. as well as requiring only a few extra lines of code.  Building some other form of logic in would require much more.  I was just very interested to see what is generally considered best practice and where the line cuts off between best practice versus feasibility/code bloat. cheers :)